# 7zip password protected zip - SHOW the password that i type

Tags: passwords, zip, 7-zip, echo

wondered if, when i unzip a pasword protected file and it says "enter the password, it will not be echoed" if i could see either what i type or paste (echoed!) OR a ***** to show that what i've pasted in has been received
thanks

Comment: If you want to see the password characters you are typing, you could type the password in a different application, e.g. an editor and cut&paste it into 7-zip.

Comment: thanks - just a lack of confidence i guess, i'm unzipping password protected files in a windows batch file, so 2 minutes per zip, and this could be the 18th paste so having the actual chars would have been great. thanks to all

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add this information and show the code of your batch file or at least the 7-Zip command you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The way that password entry dialogs behave is chosen by the program, specifically whatever code is bound to the text field.

The regular password entry field that gives you dots or asterisks was overridden by the 7zip authors to show no output whatsoever. There is no straightforward way to modify this behavior, short of modifying the (open source) code for 7zip to treat the text field differently.

As to being sure that a paste was received, @Bodo's comment is the way to go. Type the password into something else, copy it, then click into the password dialog so you can see the blinking cursor, then either right-click and paste from the context menu, or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. The cursor flashing in an input field indicates that the window has focus, and you can be sure that a paste will be received in this state.

Comment: I myself use the "Run Dialog" for a quick pasteroo.. [WinKey]+R.  I also use it to remove formatting from text pulled from other text formats.

Comment: I appreciate the extra details

Answer (score 1):

You should have written in your question that you are unzipping password protected files in a windows batch file.

In this case you you could use the command line version and specify the password with option `-p password`.

If you don't want to enter the password manually you could let your `cmd` script prompt for the password and pass it to 7-Zip as a variable, e.g.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set archive=archive.zip
echo extracting %archive%
set /p password="Enter Password: "
7z x %archive% -p%password%
endlocal
```

Depending on the version you might have to use `7za` instead of `7z`.